# Ace editor mode not working

Tags: javascript, ace-editor

I am trying to get syntax highlighting working but when changing the mode it doesn't work

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ace/1.2.9/monokai.js"></script>
    <script="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ace/1.2.9/mode-javascript.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ace/1.2.9/ace.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts.js"></script>
```

scripts.js

```
var html = ace.edit("htmlEditor");
var css = ace.edit("cssEditor");
var js = ace.edit("jsEditor");

html.setTheme("ace/theme/monokai");
css.setTheme("ace/theme/monokai");
js.setTheme("ace/theme/monokai");

var JavaScriptMode = ace.require("ace/mode/javascript").Mode;
js.session.setMode(new JavaScriptMode());
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a typo in your html `<script="` also scripts for theme and modes must be inserted after ace.js

It is better to pass names to ace and let it load modes and themes by itself

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ace/1.2.9/ace.js"></script>
<div id="htmlEditor">&lt;html&gt;</div>
<div id="cssEditor">.css { color: red }</div>
<div id="jsEditor">var js</div>
<style>
html, body {
    height: 100%;
}
#htmlEditor, #cssEditor, #jsEditor  {
height:30%
}
</style>
<script>

var html = ace.edit("htmlEditor");
var css = ace.edit("cssEditor");
var js = ace.edit("jsEditor");

html.setTheme("ace/theme/monokai");
css.setTheme("ace/theme/monokai");
js.setTheme("ace/theme/monokai");

html.session.setMode("ace/mode/html");
css.session.setMode("ace/mode/css");
js.session.setMode("ace/mode/javascript");

</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

what let me to this question is that I got `404` error when I call `setMode`

I traversed the code to see whats going on, Ace tries to `identify where Ace library` and its files are `located`, and it does that `by looking` at the `script tags` within the page, so `if` it had a `lock finding the lib location`, it set it as a `basePath` for it,

but what if Ace is **`bundled`** within a one minified main js file `main.js` it will fail and return `404`

to solve this

```
if (window.ace) {
    configureAce();
    //....
}

function configureAce() {
    // this is important in case of bundling , to have Ace knows where
    // its files are located (like themes, workers and modes)
    // and get them from that path
    window.ace.config.set("basePath", "/resources/js/lib/ace");
}
```